# Prime ideals in quotients of polynomial ring over finite field

Tags: ring-theory

Reading a book, i found this argument ($\mathbb{F}_2$ is the field with 2 elements):

consider the quotient ring:
$$\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x+1)^2$$

Then it has only one prime ideal, namely the following:
$$(x+1)\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x+1)^2$$

I've some questions:

- what does the notation $(x+1)\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x+1)^2$ means, i.e. what are the elements of this ideal?
- how can i see that this ideal is prime?
- how can i exclude that other primes are there, different from that?

Thanks for any help

Comment: For any $X$ in a commutative ring $R$, $XR=\{Xr\mid r\in R\}$ is suggestive notation for the ideal $(X)\lhd R$. In the case of $(x+1)R$, parenthesis are used, but they aren't denoting "ideal generated by" anymore, they're just holding the polynomial together. So $(x+1)R=\{(x+1)r\mid r\in R\}=(x+1)$. The denominator of your equation would be more clearly written as $((x+1)^2))$ for "the ideal generated by $(x+1)^2$, but most people just forgo the extra parentheses :) The expression $(x+1)^2 R=\{(x+1)^2r\mid r\in R\}=((x+1)^2)$ as you would expect.

Comment: The problem is that parenthesis are being overloaded with meaning :) You'll get the knack of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of those cases where knowing less makes everything a lot simpler. Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and $I$ an ideal in $R$.

If $J$ is another ideal in $R$, the ideal $JR/I$ means the image of the ideal $J$ in $R/I$, given by the natural projection $p:R \to R/I$.

As rschwieb has pointed out below, $JR/I$ is actually just $(J+I)/I$.

In this case, $J=(x+1), R = \mathbb{F}_2[x], I = (x+1)^2$.

There is a one-to-one correspondence between ideals in $R$ containing $I$ and ideals of $R/I$, sending $A \to p(A)$ for $A$ an ideal in $R$, and $B \to p^{-1}(B)$, for $B$ an ideal in $R/I$. This is also a correspondence between prime ideals. Have you seen this result?

Thus what remains to be checked is that the ideal $(x+1)$ is the only prime ideal in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ containing $(x+1)^2$. Luckily, $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ doesn't contain that many elements of small degree, so this can be checked manually.

Comment: if $J$ contains the kernel of projection of $R$ over $R/I$, i.e. if $J$ contains $I$, then $JR/I$ is simply $J/I$, meaning the classes modulo $I$ of elements in $J$. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, quite exactly. I've edited my answer to be clearer about this, either way.

Comment: ohh, so the $(x+1)$ at the beginning is not a polynomial, it is an ideal, so $(...)$ means "ideal generated by ..."

Comment: Yes @bateman...the notation of the book (which one, btw?) you quote in your post is pretty sloppy and confusing, even more for people beginning to study this stuff. Isaac's answer's on the money, and thus +1

Comment: @Solomon so $(x+1)$ surely contains its square $(x+1)^2$, moreover $(x+1)$ is prime in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ because $x+1$ is irreducible....i'm left to prove it is the unique prime.

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes (you need to prove its the unique prime contained in $(x+1)^2$, not unique in the whole ring, which is probably what you meant to write).

Comment: @Salomon let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$, containing the ideal $(x+1)^2$. $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ is PID, so write $\mathfrak{p}=(f)$. Now $(f)\supseteq (x+1)^2$ if and only of $f$ divides the polynomial $(x+1)^2=x^2+1$. But $x^2+1=(x+1)(x-1)$ and $x+1$ is the same as $x-1$ modulo $2$, so $x+1$ is the only factor of $x^2+1$

Comment: That is more or less correct, but you are using the fact that factorization is unique in this ring, which is again something you need to prove. Let me suggest the following approach. Your ring is a PID, so it suffices to check for polynomials that divide $(x+1)^2$. Now, when you multiply two polynomials in our ring, their degree cannot get smaller, so the only possible factors have degree $0$, $1$ or $2$. Degree $0$ means the polynomial $1$, which generates the unit ideal, which is not prime by definition. Degree $2$ polynomials available are $x^2, x^2 + x$, $x^2 + 1$ and $x^2 + x + 1$...

Comment: Since $x^2 = x(x)$, $x^2 +x= x(x+1)$, and $x^2 +1 = (x+1)^2$, these ideals are not prime. $x^2 + x + 1$ might be prime, but it cannot divide $x^2 + 1$. This is because you would have to multiply $x^2 + x + 1$ by a polynomial of degree $0$ to get $x^2 + 1$, and the only available polynomial is $1$, which doesn't work. Lastly, the degree $1$ polynomials available are $x,x+1$. $x+1$ is clearly prime and divides $x^2 + 1$. $x$ does not divide $x^2 + 1$, because you would have to multiply it by another degree $1$ polynomial...

Comment: and $xx = x^2 \neq x^2 + 1$, and $x(x+1) = x^2 + x \neq x^2 + 1$, so no such polynomial works. This exhaustive analysis shows us that the only prime that works must be $x+1$.

Comment: @IsaacSolomon Oh, i see this problem was not within my reach, thank you for the full-detailed computation

Comment: @IsaacSolomon Rather than writing $JR/I$, it would probably just be better to use what the projection actually is: $(J+I)/I$. Even better yet, it would be better to omit this statement completely, since you never use it. You only go on to talk about ideals containing $I$.

Comment: @rschwieb: I was trying to answer bateman's question about the meaning of the notation $(x+1)\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x+1)^2$.

Comment: @IsaacSolomon Ah, that makes sense, but describing it as a workaround for the fact that $I$ might not live in $J$ is misleading. $XR=(X)$ is just suggestive notation for the principal ideal generated by $X$. The parenthesis are just there for clarity holding the polynomial together, they aren't denoting a product of ideals. I know you understand this already, but I'm just trying to show how it might be misleading to someone like the op.

Comment: Good answer overall though :)

Comment: @rschwieb: I see what you mean. Indeed, that does appear misleading. I'll edit my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out.